# 2nd order polynomial - finding the $x$ value of the top

Tags: polynomials

I have a 2nd order polynome ($y = ax^2+bx+c$) from with I know $2.5$ points. $(450,5), (600,40)$ and $(q,0)$. I know also that $(q,0)$ is the top and $q<450$. How do I solve $q$?

Comment: What do you mean by "the top"?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose "top" means maximum.

Hint: if there is a critical point at $x=q$, then $2aq + b = 0$ so $q = -b/(2a)$ (of course $a \ne 0$), and the value of $y$ there is
$a q^2 + b q + c = c - b^2/(4a)$.

Comment: How can $x=q$ be the maximum if the points $(450,5),(q,0)$ are on the curve?

Comment: In this case the top is the minimum.

Comment: @almagest Good point.  I'll refrain from speculation on how a minimum can be called "the top".

Comment: @RobertIsrael I see your instincts were good!